# What does the class "STS_ListItem_CustomGrid" mean?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, fast-search

I'm using query soap service to search on a SharePoint site, and I get some elements that have contentclass = 'STS_ListItem_CustomGrid'. I can't find the meaning of this item anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's an item in a custom list which is displayed in quick edit view by default.